# Move the icon after the text CSS

Tags: css

A plugin generates the icon. How can I move next to the text? I tried flex order but when text wraps the icon hangs in the far right. Any solution?

```
    

h3 {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
}
.aal_anchor {
    float: unset;
    padding-right: 0;
    margin-left: 5px;
    order: 2;
    margin-top: 5px;
    position: relative;
}

.copy-to-clipboard {
    margin-left: 8px;
    order: 3;
    margin-top: -2px;
    visibility: hidden;
}
<h3 data-id="articleTOC_4"><a href="#" aria-hidden="true" class="aal_anchor" id="object-discrimination-and-recognition-of-others" data-href="#object-discrimination-and-recognition-of-others"><svg aria-hidden="true" class="aal_svg" height="16" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 16 16" width="16"><path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M4 9h1v1H4c-1.5 0-3-1.69-3-3.5S2.55 3 4 3h4c1.45 0 3 1.69 3 3.5 0 1.41-.91 2.72-2 3.25V8.59c.58-.45 1-1.27 1-2.09C10 5.22 8.98 4 8 4H4c-.98 0-2 1.22-2 2.5S3 9 4 9zm9-3h-1v1h1c1 0 2 1.22 2 2.5S13.98 12 13 12H9c-.98 0-2-1.22-2-2.5 0-.83.42-1.64 1-2.09V6.25c-1.09.53-2 1.84-2 3.25C6 11.31 7.55 13 9 13h4c1.45 0 3-1.69 3-3.5S14.5 6 13 6z"></path></svg></a><span class="copy-to-clipboard"><i class="epkbfa fa-solid fa-copy"></i></span>Object Discrimination and Recognition of OthersObject Discrimination and Recognition of OthersObject Discrimination and Recognition of Others</h3>





    order: 2;
}
```

Comment: Please add a minimal reproducible code snippet rather than a screenshot with inspect element.

Comment: Please don't send us to outside sources (that might change at any point, so the question will lose value for future readers) either. You are supposed to present a proper [mre] of your issue, directly inside the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `order: 2` in your `#context` or `.aal_anchor` element. Remove it or add `order: 0` to your `.aal_anchor` element.
and if you want to move your `copy icon`, you need to add `order:0` to your `.copy-to-clipboard` elements as well.

Answer (score 0):

try to :   `display: flex; align-items: flex-end;`

Comment: It's still in the second column :(